# "Update your browser error" when trying to access the SQL database using pyodbc in python

Tags: python, sql-server, azure

I am trying to access the SSMS database using python. Please note, that the authentication required for the SSMS login uses MFA - "Azure Active Directory - Universal with MFA". My dummy code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sqlalchemy
import pymssql 
import pyodbc

DRIVER = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"
SERVERNAME = "some.server.name.database.windows.net"
AUTHENTICATION='ActiveDirectoryInteractive'
DB = "SOME_DB"

connection_str = f'DRIVER={DRIVER};SERVER={SERVERNAME},1433;DATABASE={DB};PWD=;Encrypt=yes;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive;UID=;TrustServerCertificate=no;'


cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_str)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

query_string = '''
    select top(10) * from smth.other 
    '''
df = pd.read_sql(query_string, connection_str)
df
```

When I run the code, I am taken to the login page where I fill out my ID and password. However, when I press next, I get the following:

[image]

How would I go about solving this issue? I expect the window to display an area for me to enter my MFA info.

Comment: That browser warning has nothing to do with the Python code.

Comment: I have already update the Edge browser. And, I have already updated all of the necessary credentials in https://aka.ms/mysecurityinfo.

Comment: Actually, this popup looks like it might be from malware trying to get you to install a bogus browser update.

Comment: Nah. MFA opens browser window to handle the login info. Is the browser opened Edge? Or Chrome? It's a bit strange why it would complain about it.

Comment: Perhaps you should upgrade the ODBC drivers as well :/

Comment: @siggemannen It is the edge browser that opens up. In particular, when I run the code, Git Bash (GPD) file opens up as a pop up requesting me to enter my credentials. I do that, then then pop states the following after pressing next - "More information is required. Your organization needs more information to keep your information secure". I press Next and I get the result as displayed in the post. Thanks.

Comment: Jesus Christ! Can someone from the Azure come and help us? Please.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

To resolve the error above, you can follow these procedures:

- Log into the Edge browser with your global admin credentials. After that, try to connect to the SQL server using AD MFA authentication.
- Browse to the URL mysignins.microsoft.com, then log in with your account in question. Once logged on, you will notice a validation page where you will have to click OK. It will be something like a verification for your MFA configuration. Once you click OK, you will be able to go back and log in with this account.

Then, you will be able to connect to the SQL server using AD MFA authentication successfully with authentication windows without any error.

[image]

For more information, you can refer to this [MS Question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1332570/azure-ad-connect-mfa-unsupported-browser).